# Increase buffer size while running screen

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

I use screen as my window manager through putty. Screen has been great, but I need a way to increase my buffer when I run commands. I have no buffer when I scroll up, no std out is saved beyond my window size on any terminal.

How can I increase this I can't seem to find an option in the commands? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> doesn't seem to have what I am looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> then enter `scrollback 1234` sets your buffer to 1234 lines. You enter scrollback mode ("copy mode") with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then move in vi-style, leave copy mode with another <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Yes this definitely works, I just figured this out myself at the same time haha

Answer (score 18):

I actually figured this out after looking through the man page. Setting the screen buffer inside `.screenrc` does work, but you **can** change it inside your screen session.

<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> and typing

```
scrollback 1000
```

gives you a 1000 line buffer.

You can also set the default number of scrollback lines in `.screenrc` by using

```
defscrollback 1000
```

Then entering copy mode will let you scroll around.

Comment: The explicit instructions for `.screenrc` make this the most useful answer

Comment: It would be good to clarify even more explicitly that `scrollback` does not work in `.screenrc`, only `defscrollback` does.

Answer (score 3):

You actually do have something of a buffer, but it's invisible to most terminal emulators (which is why e. g. scroll bars don't appear to work).   One way to get at it is to enter [copy mode](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_11.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd> followed by arrow keys, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, et cetera).  The size of this buffer can be configured in `.screenrc`.  You you an change its allocation inside your screen session:

<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> and typing

```
scrollback 1000
```

gives you a 1000 line buffer.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a solution I will try this, I use Ctrl + a, Esc  to get into copy mode personally, but they both work

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yes you can in a running session like with other commands; see other answers

Comment: I noticed this.  Updating my answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change screen settings globally (for all users) then you can edit `/etc/screenrc` (Ubuntu). File path might be different on other distros.

In your case add the following lines to the file:

```
# define a bigger scrollback, default is 100 lines
defscrollback 1024
```